# Redis keys are keep increasing, EXPIRY is not set to keys

Tags: magento2, redis, cm-redissession

default,page_cache redis cache data doesnot set expiry
it always set to -1
please suggest a way to add expiry time for redis keys

Due to this RAM is overflows regularly

```
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1', 
                'database' => '2', //18
                'port' => '6379',

            ]
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1', 
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '3', //19
                'compress_data' => '0',

            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using the options , we can set expiry date

```
            'auto_expire_lifetime' => '54321',
            'auto_expire_pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]/',
            'lifetimelimit' => '555'
```